# Linux, ReportLab and LPR: Printing fails somehow

Tags: linux, python-3.x, printing, reportlab

I'm working on a python3 script that creates a batch of pdf-files using ReportLab and sends them to my local printer by calling subprocess(['LPR', filename]).

The first file is not printed completely (in fact, it's just the image - logo and the first two paragraphs), the print-outs are just non-readable nonsense.

Same behaviour when trying to print from bash.

The pdf-files do not contain anything weird, just a png-logo, some paragraphs and some tables. File size is < 20kB each.

No problems expirienced when printing these files from evince.
No problems to print other pdf files via lpr.

What's the problem with ReportLab?

Edit: Here's part of the code generating the pdf. There are some more functions, but these are called in any case. Printing stopps after Paragraph 2 in generateHeader()

class ZXPolicy:

```
doc = None
story = None
styles = None
filename = None

def __init__(self,  filename):
    self.filename = filename
    self.doc = SimpleDocTemplate(
            filename, pagesize=A4,
            rightMargin=18, leftMargin=24, topMargin=18, bottomMargin=18)
    self.story = []

    self.styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    self.styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Right', alignment=TA_RIGHT))
    self.styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY))
    self.styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Center', alignment=TA_CENTER))
    self.styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Left', alignment=TA_LEFT))
    self.styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Header', alignment=TA_CENTER, fontSize=16))
    self.styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Header2', alignment=TA_CENTER, fontSize=14))

def generateHeader(self):
    img = Image('logo.png')
    img.hAlign = 'RIGHT'
    self.story.append(img)

    style = self.styles['Right']
    self.story.append(Spacer(1, -24))
    self.story.append(Paragraph('<font size=10>xxxxx e.U.</font>', style))
    self.story.append(Paragraph('<font size=9>Allersdorf 29</font>', style))
    self.story.append(Paragraph('<font size=9>41 dfhousdhuftin i. M.</font>', style))
    self.story.append(Paragraph('<font size=9>Tel.: 07xxxxxx53 0</font>', style))
    self.story.append(
        Paragraph('<font size=9>E-Mail: offxxxxrer.at</font>',  style))
    self.story.append(
        Paragraph('<font size=9>Web: www.spoxxxxxxxt</font', style))
    self.story.append(Spacer(1, 24))

def generateTitle(self, id, adjust=True, service=False):
    if adjust is True and service is False:
        self.story.append(Paragraph('Bindungseinstellkarte',  self.styles['Header']))
    if adjust is True and service is True:
        self.story.append(Paragraph('Bindungseinstellkarte und Service-Auftrag', self.styles['Header']))
    if adjust is False and service is True:
        self.story.append(Paragraph('Service-Auftrag', self.styles['Header']))
    self.story.append(Spacer(1, 6))
    self.story.append(Paragraph('Auftragsnummer: ' + str(id), self.styles['Header2']))
    self.story.append(Spacer(1, 24))



def saveAndPrint(self, n=2):
    self.doc.build(self.story)
    self.lineprint(self.filename, n)

def lineprint(self, filename, n):
    if n > 0:
        subprocess.Popen(['lpr', 'form_letter.pdf'])
        self.lineprint(filename, n-1)
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you can post with this question?

Comment: Please show your Python code.

Comment: Just tested: Created an instance of ZXPolicy, called generateHeader(), then saveAndPrint() with n = 2. Got 2 print-outs printing 'til 'Allersdorf 29'.